# Two labels constraints in one same UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, autolayout, snapkit

I want to add two labels in every cell the left label as a description and the right label is a category and I'm using SnapKit library for Auto-Layout purpose.

The problem is I need to set a constraint for the description to not over the right label in case description is long while I'm setting the `description.numberOfLines = 0`, but it doesn't work.

```
let descriptionLabel = UILabel()
        descriptionLabel.textColor = .black
        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        let categoryLabel = UILabel()
        categoryLabel.textColor = .darkGray

        descriptionLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.left.equalToSuperview().offset(5)
            $0.top.equalToSuperview().offset(5)
            $0.right.equalTo(categoryLabel.snp.left).offset(-15).priority(.high)
            $0.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-2)
        }

        categoryLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-5)
            $0.top.equalToSuperview().offset(5)
        }
```

Expected result, description label will not come over the right category label but the actual result is not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your layout. See the

```
// 1: 2: 3:
```

comments in the code below:

```
class TestCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier: String = "test_cell_identifier"

    var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    var categoryLabel: UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        descriptionLabel = UILabel()
        categoryLabel = UILabel()
        descriptionLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        categoryLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow

        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        contentView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(categoryLabel)

        descriptionLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.left.equalToSuperview().offset(5)
            $0.top.equalToSuperview().offset(5)
            // 1: default priority is .required
            $0.right.equalTo(self.categoryLabel.snp.left).offset(-15)
            $0.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-2)
        }

        categoryLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-5)
            $0.top.equalToSuperview().offset(5)
        }

        // 2: prevent category label from being compressed
        categoryLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

        // 3: prevent category label from stretching if description label is really short
        categoryLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This what am looking for! Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A high priority means it would be broken when description label text is long

1- Make it

```
$0.right.equalTo(categoryLabel.snp.left).offset(-15)
```

2- Set horizontal `contentCompressionResistance` of `categoryLabel` to 1000

Comment: Is this right? `categoryLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal)`

Comment: Yes now it is working like charm, but it is damaged while scrolling the tableView and here I already use reusable cell

Comment: what's damaged ? can you share screenshots ? also before `return cell` do `cell.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: I used `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` also please check this image, result is not okay https://pasteboard.co/IdX2hWk.png

Comment: I think we have to use `textAlignment = .right` for category label and `setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal)` for descriptionLabel what do you think?